# How can I set IE 9 on Windows 7 Pro 64-bit to ALWAYS run as administrator?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer

On other applications you just right-click the application shortcut, select properties, select the compatibility tab, and then select the option to run as administrator.

However, these options appear to be grayed out and unselectable on IE.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems like a particularly bad idea.

Comment: As Sara rightly says, don't do this.  Do you have a related problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Don't do this.

IE9 has taken many steps to be a more secure browser, and as such it shouldn't be run in Administrator mode, unless you're trying to resolve another particular problem.

If you look at the `Compatibility` Tab on the proper window it clearly states

> Compatibility modes cannot be set on this program because it is part of this version of Windows.

So if you really wanted to change the Privilege Level you would have to circumvent some deeper in Windows.

You would be better off finding a work-around to the problem you think needs to be solved by always running in administrator mode.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're looking in the right spot.

Go to the *Shortcut* tab and click the *Advanced...* button:

[image]

Then check the *Run as administrator* checkbox

[image]

You will still have to confirm the privilege elevation every time you use the shortcut.

Comment: Only works when launching the shortcut, not every time though